# Coupled and higher order ODE's

Tags: plot

I want to draw the trajectory of a ball that has been launched in the gravitational field, we take into account air resistance by a quadratic law :

[image: Diagram]

For more simplicity I took alpha = 0. So the equations of movement are :

[image: velocity]

I would especially like to plot the velocity :

[image: velocity]

And we can rewrite the equation of movement into :

[image: movement]

So I would finally like to plot the trajectory of my ball.

The values are :

t0 = 0s | te = 10s | m = 58e-3 kg | k = 1.15e-3 SI | z0 = 200m | x0 = 0m | vx0 = 10 m.s-1 |vz0 = 0 m.s-1 | g = 9.81 m.s-2

I am not sure about the syntax on LaTeX. I would rather do it with `pst-ode`. But any methods to produce a good pdf will be welcomed.

Can anyone help me please?

**Edit:** thanks to @AlexG for his answer. I wanted to share the final result I made:

[image: This]

*Pardon my French.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coupled, higher order ODEs are no problem at all.

First, we convert the original system of two 2nd order into a system of four 1st order ODEs:

[image]

Then, we put everything together (4 ODEs, 4 initial conditions). Note that with `\pstODEsolve` we can make post-calculations on the solution vector (computing |**v**| from its components) while writing the output table.

Typeset with `pdflatex --shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% solve ODE in auxiliary document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{solve.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\def\vZero{10} % initial velocity
\def\alpha{0}  % elevation angle

\begin{document} 
\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{table}{
  t | x[0] | x[2] | sqrt(x[1]^2+x[3]^2)  % save in `table2.dat': t, x, z, |v|=sqrt(v_x^2 + v_z^2)
}{ 0 }{ 10 }{ 250 }{                     % t_0, t_e, N=250
  0 |
  \vZero * cos(\alpha) |                 % initial conditions x(0), v_x(0), z(0), v_z(0)
  200 |
  \vZero * sin(\alpha)
}{ 
  x[1] |                                 % RHS, (4 equations)
  -1.15*10^-3/(58*10^-3) * sqrt(x[1]^2+x[3]^2) * x[1] |
  x[3] |
  -1.15*10^-3/(58*10^-3) * sqrt(x[1]^2+x[3]^2) * x[3] - 9.81
}
dummy text
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\immediate\write18{latex solve}
\immediate\write18{dvips solve}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf -dNOSAFER solve.ps}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

Trajectory:\\[1ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
%    axis equal,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$z$,
    ylabel style={rotate=-90}
  ]
  \addplot [blue] table [x index=1, y index=2] {table.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Velocity:\\[1ex]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$|\mathrm{v}|$,
    ylabel style={rotate=-90}
  ]
  \addplot [blue] table [x index=0, y index=3] {table.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it meets all my expectations.

Comment: I have just noticed two little typos:  `x[1]` and `x[3]` have been respectively forgotten for second and fourth ODE. And the `x index` should be 1 for first plot.

Comment: @Axel Oh, yeah, thank you! I am going to correct this. Now the curves are much more interesting. One can see, how the drag comes into play as the velocity increases.

Comment: @Axel Now, one can also play with the elevation angle.